How can I change the Z-probe home location on an Ender 3 V2?
I have an Ender3 V2 using the current mriscoc firmware and a CR-touch probe; basically all stock.
I am currently trying to print two colors, one overlaid above the other, using a Z-offset in Cura.  I do this a lot and offset my (smaller) model so that the Z-probe homing location, in the center of my plate, does not contact the model.  The model I am currently printing is too large to offset and the result is that the Z-probe will contact it instead of the plate as it homes.
Is there a way to temporarily change the "home" location of the Z-probe to a different location on the plate, other than the center, so that it will miss the model?

The default mriscoc doesn't have Z_SAFE_HOMING enabled, so you have changed the configuration, correct? So whatever you do, the printer will home in the middle of the bed first. There might be a way to bypass this, but, I do need to test this first!
